# Eignfunctions of an elliptic operator

Tags: harmonic-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, elliptic-pde, schrodinger-operators

I am looking for a reference which makes it possible to say that one can devellop $f$ in the form of the sentence underlined by the yellow.

Thank you in advance.

[image]